# Can an IE8 Accelerator be made to launch a process?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, accelerator

I want to create an IE8 Accelerator that will launch Remote Desktop (mstsc) with the hostname being the selected text.  But the accelerators I've seen only direct the browser to URLs.  Can an Accelerator launch mstsc.exe?

Comment: No, but a script attached to a Context Menu should work: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa753589(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the only thing you are able to "launch" are URLs, as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc289775%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Correct. The link is restricted to HTTP/HTTPS URIs, so launching a local file won't work. You could build a loopback HTTP server or similar hack, but you probably shouldn't.

Comment: Oh, nice to see some semi-official voice here.

Answer (score 0):

It can do pretty much anything.

http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/Charles/IE8-Accelerators/